# Dispatcher.useSyncExternalStore is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this error. This started happening when I was trying to install the react-native-imaged-card-view package and forced some dependencies. I think I broke something. Please help me.

```
TypeError: dispatcher.useSyncExternalStore is not a function. (In 'dispatcher.useSyncExternalStore(subscribe, getSnapshot, getServerSnapshot)', 'dispatcher.useSyncExternalStore' is undefined)

This error is located at:
    in ExpoStatusBar (created by LandingPage)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by LandingPage)
    in LandingPage (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Screen)
    in MaybeFreeze (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by AuthStack)
    in AuthStack (created by Routes)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by Routes)
    in Routes (created by Providers)
    in AuthProvider (created by Providers)
    in Providers (created by App)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in DevAppContainer (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ReactFiberErrorDialog.js:43:2 in showErrorDialog
at navigation/AuthProvider.js:32:13 in stateChanged
at navigation/AuthProvider.js:31:25 in stateChanged
at node_modules/@firebase/util/dist/index.esm2017.js:1150:0 in <global>
at node_modules/@firebase/util/dist/index.esm2017.js:1312:13 in Sha1#compress_
```

Comment: Have you tried reverting your dependencies to what you had before you installed the new package and forced others?

Comment: How do I do this?